# Can I bake an animation from a curve modifier?

Tags: animation, modifiers

Basically, I have an object with an array and then a curve modifier to create a conveyor belt that I want to use in Unjty. In Blender, this animates fine by moving the object along the X axis, but of course this just ends up being an X axis translation in Unity. Is there any way to just bake the mesh's animation to keyframes? And if not, is there a reliable way to get animated conveyor tracks into Unity from Blender?

Comment: Using [bake action](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38054/935) should work for you.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work because it just maintains the same single lateral motion as originally animated. I need something that will bake the conveyer animation, not an object moving along a straight line.

Comment: see if this helps: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/64215/how-do-i-make-an-animation-from-a-curve