# Bake animation with modifiers, including "real" location of vertices

Tags: animation, modifiers

I have created an animation with the displacement modifier (for a fish based on https://youtu.be/58lc8sLpJzY). Now I want to bake the animation to keyframes. Additionally, I need the locations of some vertices for further processing in animation nodes later.

- The [solution](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/64283/121051) with exporting as mdd and then re-importing shape keys doesn`t work for me. After importing, the scale and direction of movement changes and shape keys are keyframed, so it is hard to correct.
- Object - animation - bake to... doesn`t work. The positions of the vertices are not updating.
- Applying the modifier doesn`t work. Then the fish remains frozen in the first "shape" and just moves straight.

Is there a better way to bake the animation after modifiers, including location of vertices?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a duplicate of the object for every unique frame of the animation.
2. Apply the modifier separately on every object, with each object on a different frame.
3. Use "Join as Shapes" to combine all the objects into one. (Menu next to the Shape Keys panel, or `ops.object.join_shapes()`.)

This will produce a single object with a shape key for every frame of the animation. You can then keyframe these shape keys to show on the correct frames.

Comment: If I duplicate the objects, they still keep moving. Should I create 100 still objects first? But then how do I move them to the individual position in each frame? Sorry, not sure what you mean. Could you please be a bit more specific? I am quite new to blender.

Comment: @ChrisM No. You want them to move. You'd then apply all their modifiers on different frames, so you have one final still mesh for each frame. Then join those objects as shape keys, to have one object with one shape key for each frame.